# Can I delete Zapotec.bmp & Soap Bubbles.bmp etc?

Tags: windows-xp

In my `C:\WINDOWS\` folder there are bmp files called `Zapotec.bmp`, `Soap Bubbles.bmp`, `winnt.bmp` etc. What are they needed for? I was wondering if I can safely delete them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are used as wallpapers in windows. You can safely remove them.
If you want to be safe, put them in a folder from where you could restore
them afterwards.

Let me ask, why would you want to delete them?

Comment: I was just cleaning up unnecessary files and folders. I deleted KB log files, and I saw them there. My hard drive is working a bit slower nowadays. I want to do a defrag afterwards..

Comment: Those files aren't going to make a significant difference, but they are safe to delete.  Deleting hotfix uninstallers will save you a lot more space.  If you just want to clean out junk [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) is a lot faster, easier, and safer than trying to do it yourself.  If you're doing it as a learning experience, by all means go ahead.  Then run CCleaner afterwards to see what you missed.